# Possible bug? Avatar is missing from flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, gravatar, profile-picture

I just noticed today that my avatar was missing from the flair images. Here's what my [flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8205/hmemcpy/flair) looks like today:

[image]

People on twitter tell me that it looks fine to them, but I don't see it.
I haven't made any changes to my Gravatar either.

Is it just me?

Comment: No repro for me.

Comment: Your flair appears broken to me as well... infact, [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt/flair) is broken in the same fashion..

Comment: @Matt Both of your flair look fine to me.

Comment: Have almost the same issue, mine only missing the basic SO picture, having the others. For me both of your flairs are broken (@Matt & @hmemcpy).

Comment: @hims056 very odd, the xml response says Access Denied for me...

Comment: Gravatar was pretty unreliable for me the last few days. Perhaps SE got a timeout while fetching the gravatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a server with permissions that were not quite right.  This has been resolved.

Comment: It's still 404'd for me, do the caches need to be flushed?

Comment: Looks ok to me:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151015/richard-j-ross-iii/flair

Comment: My flair was always fine. I was refering to the OPs.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8205/hmemcpy/flair works as well

Comment: Nope, not for me ;( on mobile safari if that makes a difference, iOS 6. My flair is fine, hmemcpy's isn't.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BtXAn.png weird.... this is from my iPhone running IOS6.0.1

Comment: Probably a local cache thing. Ill let you know tomorrow if the problem persists

Comment: Seems fine to me

Comment: Yup, I can confirm the problem is solved!

Comment: This problem is most definitely not solved, and the issue only seems to happen on main, not meta. http://imgur.com/W18Fe, http://imgur.com/8kt3l

Comment: I identified yet another server with incorrect permissions - I have looked at all of them and they should be fixed now.